# twitter bootstrap - moving objects to navbar when collapsed bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I got a topnavbar which disappears when the website gets loaded on a mobile device but I would like the content that is on that topnavbar to appear on the collapsed main navigation.

[TOPNAVBAR](http://i.gyazo.com/e5226ca43130211a97c1d640539bd728.png)

[COLLAPSED NAVIGATION](http://i.gyazo.com/2cd84880dcafa10755d8ebf83d05b4a3.png)
How would I be able to achieve this or is this even possible or do I have to create a class specially for the collapsed menu?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I sometimes do is the following:

1) You create your `top-menu` container for big devices

2) You create the same menu in your collapse container for small devices

3) Use css and `@media` to switch between to 2 lists

```
<header>
    <div class="container">

    <!-- Top menu for not mobile devices -->  
    <div id="top-menu" class="clearfix">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li>
                 <a href="#">
                     TopItem1
                 </a>
             </li>
             <li>
                  <a href="#">
                     TopItem2
                  </a>
             </li>
          </ul>
      </div>

      <!-- Navigation bar -->
      <div class="navbar navbar-default">

          <div class="navbar-header">

              <!-- Toggle menu -->
              <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>

              <!-- Logo -->
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="/nl/">

              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

               <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                   <li>
                       <a href="#">
                           Item1
                       </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Item2
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            Item2
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Same top menu links for small devices -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="top-responsive">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            TopItem1
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                         <a href="#">
                            TopItem2
                         </a>
                    </li>
                 </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

Standard css style:

```
#top-responsive {
    display: none;
}

#top-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

With `@media` for small devices:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) 
{
    #top-responsive {
        display: block;
    }

    #top-menu {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VDesign/qyosv002/

**EDIT:**

Like Vicente said, Bootstrap provides utility classes that does the same thing I do.
You can find the intell about it on the website of Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: You can also use the responsive utility classes which are available in bootstrap. See: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: @vicente you are right, I will added to my answer, thanks for the headsup!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. @vicente your solution is also very good, this way I can get rid of some custom classes that would hide the topbar.